# @ConversationScoped is spoiling the filtering and sorting options in form, @ViewScoped works fine

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, view-scope, conversation-scope

I'm working on a small course passing project, and I have a problem.

The manager.xhtml is a JSF page, it is used to view the data from database, sort them, filter them, delete entries and edit those entries. When I'm using @ViewScoped in Manager.java - everything EXCEPT the edit part works just fine. The "Edit" link is sending the user to another page - edit.xhtml. After I used @ConversationScoped to be able to read data send from manager.xhml in edit.xhtml. After using @ConversationScoped the entry editing option worked flawlessly, but it started making errors in some of the filtering/sorting options - sorting by CATEGORY started pulling out errors like "Name is null", filtering by price - the same.

Here is the code.

manager.xhtml

Here is the form in which the problems start to occur while using @ConversationScoped

```
    <h:form>

        <h:panelGrid id="filterPanel" columns="7">
            <f:ajax render="filterValue" event="change" execute="filterValue">
                #{text.sort}
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{manager.order}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="cargoName" itemLabel="#{text.cargo_name}"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="price" itemLabel="#{text.cargo_price}"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="category" itemLabel="#{text.cargo_category}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>


                <h:selectOneMenu id="filterType" value="#{manager.filterType}"> 

                    <f:selectItem itemValue="CARGO_NAME" itemLabel="#{text.cargo_name}"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="PRICE" itemLabel="#{text.cargo_price_filter}"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="CATEGORY" itemLabel="#{text.cargo_category}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>

                <h:panelGroup id="filterValue">
                    <h:panelGroup id="filterValues">
                        <h:inputText id="filterValueInput" value="#{manager.filterValue}" rendered="#{manager.filterType == 'CARGO_NAME'
                                                                    or manager.filterType == 'PRICE'}"
                                     required="#{manager.filterType == 'PRICE'}"/>
                        <h:message for="filterValueInput"/>
                        <h:inputText id="filterValueInput2" value="#{manager.filterValue2}" rendered="#{manager.filterType == 'PRICE'}" 
                                     required="#{manager.filterType == 'PRICE'}"/>
                        <h:message for="filterValueInput2"/>

                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="cargoForm" value="#{manager.filterValue}" rendered="#{manager.filterType == 'CATEGORY'}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{text.cargo_text_BOOKS}" itemValue="BOOKS"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{text.cargo_text_CALENDARS}" itemValue="CALENDARS"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{text.cargo_text_CD}" itemValue="CD"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{text.cargo_text_EBOOKS}" itemValue="EBOOKS"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{text.cargo_text_OFFICE}" itemValue="OFFICE"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{text.cargo_text_VINYL}" itemValue="VINYL"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGroup>

            </f:ajax>

            <h:commandButton action="#{manager.filter}" value="#{text.button_refresh}"/>
            <h:commandButton action="#{manager.reset}" value="#{text.button_reset}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
```

edit.xhtml

The edition form - it's filled with the data of selected entry ONLY when using @ConversationScoped:

Getting the ID sent by manager.xhtml

```
        <h:inputHidden value="#{manager.editCargo.id}"/>
```

In the form the data is taken from manager like this:

```
            <h:inputText id="cargoName" value="#{manager.editCargo.cargoName}" required="true">
            </h:inputText>
```

button to save changes:

```
        <h:commandButton value="#{text.edit_button}" action="#{manager.update}"/>
```

Manager.java - unnecesary code removed.

```
@ConversationScoped
@ManagedBean
public class Manager implements Serializable {

@Inject
private CargoRepository repository; // tworzy nową instancję objektu CargoRepository
private List<Cargo> cargos; // tworzy listę obiektów Cargo
private String order = CARGO_NAME; // musi istnieć by zainicjować jakąś zmienną order, ponieważ manager.xhtml już na starcie sortuje po order więc nie może być null.
private FilterType filterType = FilterType.CARGO_NAME;
private String filterValue;
private String filterValue2;

@Inject
private Conversation conversation;
```

Getters and setters removed...

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    cargos = repository.getAll(order);
    editCargo = new Cargo();
}

public void filter() {
    if (filterType == FilterType.PRICE) {
        cargos = repository.getAll(filterType, filterValue, filterValue2, order);
    } else {
        cargos = repository.getAll(filterType, filterValue, order);
    }
}

public void resetFilterValue() {
    filterValue = "";
    filterValue2 = "";
}

public String edit(Cargo cargo) {
    conversation.start();
    editCargo = cargo;
    return "edit";
}

public String update() {
    conversation.end();
    repository.update(editCargo);
    System.out.println(editCargo.toString());
    init();
    return "manager";
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @BalusC - i understand that, but I have absolutely no idea what is causing the problem. Too many strange things are happening while using ConversationScoped to make this so simple as mcve page is saying. I could of course write a simple version of the app, but there may be a situation that the errors won't occur in the simpler version...

Comment: This problem is surely reproducible without e.g. `<h1>` and just 1 column/field instead of all 6. The right tree (the cause and inherently thus also the solution) is easier found if you remove the forest (the irrelevant code not actually contributing to the problem).

Comment: @BalusC i'll edit the code in a few minutes.

Comment: @BalusC ok, I managed to cut as much unnecessary code as I could, and added some coments. I hope it is better now. Thanks for the advices.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to repair the problem.

Instead of:

```
@ConversationScoped
@ManagedBean
```

I have used

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
```

The @SessionScoped was imported from

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
```

I removed EVERYTHING related to @ConversationScoped including

```
@Inject
private Conversation conversation;
```

and every usage of

```
conversation.start();
conversation.end();
```

Everything is working flawlessly now.